# Understanding boldSystemFontOfSize:

Tags: ios, fonts, uifont

I'd like to know why my bold font isn't bold in my app? I tried setting label in Interface Builder to System-Bold but the font didn't look bold. So I started investigating and found that the font the label was using was actually `.HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4` with a weight of `bold`. But it looks to be medium instead of bold. So I went and tried setting the font in code to bold using `boldSystemFontOfSize:` and the font returned again was wrong.

So calling boldSystemFontOfSize will return a medium font.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24]);
<UICTFont: 0x7f9ed0f4f380> font-family: ".HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 24.00pt
```

Is this a bug in UIFont? Or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem. Everything works as intended.

These methods return fonts that are appropriate for the operating system that you are using. "Bold" doesn't mean "bold", it means "bold in comparison to other user interface elements". So when Apple decides to change the way text in iOS or MacOS X looks, you don't have to change your code. In iOS 7 and 8 fonts tend to be rather slim, so when you ask for Bold, you get medium to match the overall theme.

Comment: So if my designer really wants bold, what should I tell him? :) Then I cant use IB fonts at all but would have to set them in code and really define the font that I want by writing "Helvetica-Neue-Bold"? Which would be bad once iOS9 is out and system font is not Helvetica any more?!?... huch... not so cool!

Comment: If your designer is asking for "bold" but not a specific font (and is upset with the system bold), your designer is confused. There is no such thing as "bold" except as a comparison to other things in the same family. Your designer can either specify *every* font explicitly, or can specify "bold" and take the system bold (which happens to be classified as Medium of that font). The latter is strongly encouraged by Apple.